# I can't change the compatibility level of the database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a table in SLQ Server 2008 with an attribute of type DATE, but I had a problem :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near '100'.

when I did a search I found that i should change the compatibility level of the database, so I did it and I wrote this code

```
ALTER DATABASE Gestion_bib SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100;
```

I get the error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '100'.
```

Comment: Are you sure that the SQL Server installation is SQL Server 2008. Check with `select @@version`. You will get that error if you are on SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Oh !! I really forgot I used ./SQLEXPRESS as the Sever name to connect with the database

Comment: @ Mikael Eriksson I having this same issue with sql server 2005; could you help me on this